# How to avoid using collect() for custom, iterative DataFrame transformations in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm struggling to *efficiently* implement a data transformation in `pyspark`. The goal is decompose a hexadecimal string into several intelligible data elements ("sub-signals") residing in distinct columns.

The input `DataFrame` contains a `StringType()` column `data_element_value` composed of hexadecimal strings.

[image: Input DataFrame]

Each `data_element_value` string encodes several *sub-signals* like the example diagram below.

[image: Hexadecimal string encodes several sub-signals]

Exactly *how* to decompose (think "index") and translate each sub-signal is given by a look-up table ("the decode DataFrame") like the one below:

[image: Decode DataFrame]

Each row in the decode DataFrame tells us how to decompose and translate the hexadecimal string. The `Beginning` column says which byte to start at (recall each hex character is a *nibble* and two nibbles represent one byte) and the `Size` column tells us how many bytes to grab -- that's the decomposition. When each sub-signal is decomposed this way, we convert the hexadecimal substring into a base-10 integer and apply a linear map with the `Slope` and `Offset` columns -- that's the translation. The fully transformed `DataFrame` should look like this:

[image: Final Transformed DataFrame]

**What I've Tried**

I have `split` the hexadecimal string into a new column `data_element_value_split` of type `ArrayType(StringType())`. This column provides a simple way to index each sub signal of a hexadecimal *array*. Then I `collect()` the input and decode DataFrames and iterate through them row-by-row, indexing the hexadecimal array for each sub-signal and applying the linear map (minimum working example is provided in code below to reproduce this easily).

My understanding is that calling `collect()` will restrict all data processing to the driver node, which makes for a non-distributed, inefficient data transformation. Due to the large amount of data that is needing to constantly be transformed, this seems like a bad idea. I think it would be okay to `collect()` the smaller decode dataframe(s) and `broadcast` them to the workers, but I don't think it's okay to `collect()` the larger input DataFrame(s). Is there a way to implement this transformation in a distributed, efficient manner? Perhaps with User Defined Functions? Any solution would help, but using the Spark [RDD API is not preferred since it is not supported on Databricks Unity Catalog Clusters using Shared Access mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/compute/access-mode-limitations#--shared-access-mode-limitations).

**My (inefficient) Solution**

```
# Create sample input DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    FloatType,
    IntegerType
    StringType,
    StructField,
    StructType
)
input_data = [
    ("encoded_signal_1", "17080904792000"),
    ("encoded_signal_2", "170809041e2401"),
]
input_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("data_element", StringType()),
        StructField("data_element_value", StringType()),
    ]
)
df_input = spark.createDataFrame(input_data, schema=input_schema)

# Create sample decode DataFrame
decode_data = [
    ("sub_signal_1", 1, 0, 1.0, 2000,),
    ("sub_signal_2", 1, 1, 1.0, 0,),
    ("sub_signal_3", 1, 2, 1.0, 0,),
    ("sub_signal_4", 4, 3, 0.015625, 0,),
]
decode_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("SignalName", StringType()),
        StructField("Size", IntegerType()),
        StructField("Beginning", IntegerType()),
        StructField("Slope", FloatType()),
        StructField("Offset", IntegerType()),
    ]
)
df_decode = spark.createDataFrame(decode_data, schema=decode_schema)

# Transform using collect()
df_input_split = df_input.withColumn("data_element_value_split", split("data_element_value", r"(?<=\G..)"))  # decompose hex into bytes
decode_rows = df_decode.collect()
input_rows = df_input_split.collect()
input_rows_decoded = []
for input_row in input_rows:

    input_row_dict = input_row.asDict()
    for decode_row in decode_rows:

        start_byte = decode_row.Beginning
        end_byte = start_byte + decode_row.Size
        sub_signal = "".join(input_row.data_element_value_split[start_byte:end_byte])
        sub_signal_decoded = int(sub_signal, 16)*decode_row.Slope + decode_row.Offset
        input_row_dict[decode_row.SignalName] = sub_signal_decoded
    input_rows_decoded.append(input_row_dict)
df_final = spark.createDataFrame(input_rows_decoded)
display(df_final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `df_decode` is much smaller than `df_input`, we can create a [Column object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html) for each subsignal by iterating over `df_decode`.

```python
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = [
    (F.conv(
      F.substring(F.col('data_element_value'),  # take the substring of the data
        int(col[2])*2+1,                        # from start
        int(col[1])*2),                         # with length
      16, 10).cast('double')                    # use conv to convert from hex -> dec
       * float(col[3])                          # multiply with slope
       + float(col[4]))                         # and add the offset
       .alias(f"sub_signal_{(i+1)}")            # rename column
       for i, col in enumerate(np.array(df_decode.collect()))]
cols = df_input.columns + cols                  # add the original columns

df_input.select(cols).show()
```

Output:

```
+----------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|    data_element|data_element_value|sub_signal_1|sub_signal_2|sub_signal_3|  sub_signal_4|
+----------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|encoded_signal_1|    17080904792000|      2023.0|         8.0|         9.0|     1172608.0|
|encoded_signal_2|    170809041e2401|      2023.0|         8.0|         9.0|1079440.015625|
+----------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```